# C# - Cannot get index of current row in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

Pretty simple, as mentioned. Using the following code, I get the following errors whether or not I stay in the current row after modifying cell contents.

***NOTE: I am only using this method call for troubleshooting.***

CODE:

```
private void handler_dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender,DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){         
        try{Console.WriteLine(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex);}catch{}      //'System.NullReferenceException'
        try{Console.WriteLine(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);}catch{}     //'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
        try{Console.WriteLine(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex);}catch{} //'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
        try{Console.WriteLine(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index);}catch{}          //'System.NullReferenceException'
}
```

ERRORS:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication4.exe
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication4.exe
```

Comment: Do you get the errors only when you start your application? Or also when you change the value of a cell?

Comment: What is the value of `e.RowIndex`?

Comment: Why not use sender as DataGridViewCell and get the properties from there?

Comment: It may be better to use the properties of the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs e`.

Comment: e and sender are not relevant, as this is not the function being used. On that note, it also doesn't seem to matter where I call this function, but I'll try using e and sender suggestions as mentioned and post results. These errors occur only when changing the value of the cell, and THEN changing the cell in order to apply the changes.

Comment: They are very relevant and it isn't a function you call, the grid calls it.  Your code should just react to it.  You have to show us how you are calling it.

Comment: e.RowIndex actually works. Not sure if this can be implemented in the actual method that is using this though. The method using this is an event triggered by the pushing of a button, in this case, "SAVE". I want to save the edits for THAT row. This uses the index of the row to index an array of ID's for the SQL "UPDATE" query.

Comment: @RyanHaley do you have actual code written for your UPDATE query.. what you are wanting to do is not that difficult but you seem to have not posted all relevant code
`var editedCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    var newValue = editedCell.Value;`

Comment: @MethodMan : The UPDATE query is also irrelevant. The method is basically this: ***private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){ //SAVE***, and ***int    rowIndex  ="something I am trying to do here"1;, and ***string HLD_ID    = RecordIDs[rowIndex];***

Comment: wait, I think I know what I can do here. I need to split up the responsibilities of gathering this index, since the button event will not know the row index. HOWEVER, the cell contents changed event DOES know the index, which can be used when the button event is called.

Comment: if you have a Edit button on your DataGridView then you can get the exact RowId or Index let me post an example real quick

Comment: I think Lars nailed it with e.RowIndex. I elevated the scope of the rowIndex  integer variable, which is set each time a cell is modified. When the button event happens, it can reference this variable in the array of stored ID's. PERFECTION. Thanks everyone. Please post an answer so I can mark this as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `asp:GridView` and I have a Link Button that has Edit button I want to get the RowId of the item I clicked so I would do the following on the Link Buttons Click Event.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" Text="Edit" OnClick="lnkEdit_Click" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Next inside I will have an event and do the following to figure out what Row was clicked in the GridView

```
protected void lnkEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
    GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)lnk.NamingContainer;
    string tempID = gv.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    ViewState["KeyId"] = tempID;
}
```

Comment: I am a fan of your work, MethodMan (not a stalker, promise), but I am trying to make this interface more intuitive, hence less buttons. However, this is definitely getting used in another project I was working on!

Comment: Wait, couldn't the "SAVE" button use this same concept? - Purpose being, when the grid is populated at startup, the cell changed event is called hundreds of times. This link button would be very efficient, as it would only make the index reference once. Efficient and clean, thank you sir!

Comment: you can do it on the Save button by accessing the `ViewState["KeyId"]` providing that the save is done / happening on the same Page. or you could store the value in a Session variable..

Answer (score 0):

```
int SelectedRowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView1.Rows[SelectedRowIndex];
string a = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["iDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
```

Comment: Feel free to add an explanation what your answer does.  Four space indent for code samples.

Comment: Can't use dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;, it throws an error. This is the problem we're facing here.